# PHP: using preg_replace with htmlentities

Tags: php, regex

I'm writing an `RSS` to `JSON parser` and as a part of that, I need to use `htmlentities()` on any tag found inside the description tag. Currently, I'm trying to use `preg_replace()`, but I'm struggling a little with it. My current (non-working) code looks like:

```
$pattern[0] = "/\<description\>(.*?)\<\/description\>/is";
$replace[0] = '<description>'.htmlentities("$1").'</description>';
$rawFeed = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $rawFeed);
```

If you have a more elegant solution to this as well, please share. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple.  Use `preg_replace_callback`:

```
function _handle_match($match)
{
    return '<description>' . htmlentities($match[1]) . '</description>';
}

$pattern = "/\<description\>(.*?)\<\/description\>/is";
$rawFeed = preg_replace_callback($pattern, '_handle_match', $rawFeed);
```

It accepts any callback type, so also methods in classes.

Comment: How would you change the pattern to match the content of all nested nodes? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The more elegant solution would be to employ [SimpleXML](http://php.net/simplexml). Or a third party library such as [XML_Feed_Parser](http://pear.php.net/package/XML_Feed_Parser) or [Zend_Feed](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.feed.html) to parse the feed.

Here is a SimpleXML example:

```
<?php
$rss = file_get_contents('http://rss.slashdot.org/Slashdot/slashdot');
$xml = simplexml_load_string($rss);

foreach ($xml->item as $item) {
    echo "{$item->description}\n\n";
}
?>
```

Keep in mind that RSS and RDF and Atom look different, which is why it can make sense to employ one of the above libraries I mentioned.

Comment: I am actually using simpleXML, but the problem is that any embedded HTML inside the description tag also becomes an object, which is why I am entity encoding it first.

Comment: Your feed is broken then. Good feeds wrap HTML and similar in CDATA.