# preg_replace regular expression change particular symbols inside tag

Tags: regex, preg-replace

I have a **span** element and some text inside it.
Sometimes the content of this element includes the other elements (tags) as well.

For example:

```
<span id="span_id"><a href="http://someurl" title="sometitle">value</a></span>
```

What I need to do is to convert all the '<' inside **span** to "~lt~" and all ">" to "~gt~".
There could be a hierarchy, e.g. inside **a** element there could be **img** tag and etc.

So if the input is:

```
<span id="span_id"><a href="http://someurl" title="sometitle"><img src="http://anotherurl"/></a></span>
```

The output should be:

```
<span id="span_id">~lt~a href="http://someurl" title="sometitle"~gt~~lt~img src="http://anotherurl"/~gt~~lt~/a~gt~</span>
```

Thanks!

**UPD**
I have taken the solution from here [PHP: using preg_replace with htmlentities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128350/php-using-preg-replace-with-htmlentities)

Comment: What if there's a `span` within a `span`? e.g., `<span id="span_id"><a href="">some text is <span style="color: green;">GREEN</span>!</a></span>`  I'm guessing you want everything inside `span#span_id` even if it's another `span`. Right? In that case, an HTML parser + [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/str_replace) might be a good idea.

Comment: Well, actually there are no span inside span and I can assume it as a premise. The problem with using HTML parser is that inside SPAN - there is not always correct HTML, so for example it could be opening of A tag without closing it. That is why I decided to preprocess the text with regular expression. Then parse it, do something, and then replace values back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said, you need to accept answers for questions you have asked.

Here is a solution which uses the `preg_replace_callback()` function. The main regex matches an "innermost" SPAN element (but see: CAVEATs below). The callback function processes the element contents, replacing each `<` with `&lt;` and each `>` with `&gt;`:

```php
function escapeSpanContents($text) {
    return preg_replace_callback('%
        # Match an innermost SPAN element.
        (<span\b[^>]*>)   # $1: SPAN element start tag.
        (                 # $2: SPAN element contents.
          [^<]*           # Non-start or end tag < chars. {normal*}
          (?:             # Begin {(special normal*)*} construct.
            <             # {special} is any < that is...
            (?!/?span\b)  # neither a <span or </span
            [^<]*         # More {normal*}
          )*              # Finish "Unrolling-the-Loop"
        )                 # End $2: SPAN element contents.
        (</span\s*>)      # $3: SPAN element end tag.
        %sx', '_escapeSpanContentsCallback', $text);
}
function _escapeSpanContentsCallback($matches) {
    $matches[2] = str_replace(
        array('<', '>'),
        array('&lt;', '&gt;'),
        $matches[2]);
    return $matches[1] . $matches[2] . $matches[3];
}
```

**CAVEATS:** This will fail to match SPAN elements having start tag attributes containing angle brackets (which should be rare). It will also erroneously match SPAN "elements" appearing inside COMMENTs, SCRIPTs and STYLE elements. Although this solution will do a pretty decent job, **it is best to use an HTML parser if you need 100% reliable results.**

Comment: Thanks for the info, I actually used: `$html = preg_replace_callback('@\<span(.*?)\>(.*?)\<\/span\>@mis','_handle_match', $html); function _handle_match($match)
 {
  return '<span'.$match[1].'>' . str_replace(array('<','>','"'),array('&lt;', '&gt;', '&quot;'), $match[2]) . '</span>';
 `